# Filter only one row within groups with conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hello everyone I would need help in order to keep only one rowwithin groups in a dataframe but with specific orders.

For instance :

```
Groups Names
G1     ABAJGGG78
G1     UGEIEGU
G1     YP_EIEIYE 
G2     AOIGOEGO 
G2     BEHEHEO
G3     EGEOEGO 
G3     XP_EHHEHE
G3     XP_EHEHEZ
G3     YP_EHXXZ
G4     ZHHEHE 
G4     XP_ddhhd
```

so here the Idea is that I would like to keep in priority within groups `Names` with `YP_` on it, then `XP_`, and if there is no `YP_` or `XP_`, then I keep the `first one`.
Here I should get :

```
Groups Names
G1     YP_EIEIYE 
G2     AOIGOEGO 
G3     YP_EHXXZ
G4     XP_ddhhd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do `Categorical` then `argsort` and `drop_duplicates`

```
out = df.iloc[pd.Categorical(df.Names.str[:3],['XP_','YP_']).argsort()].drop_duplicates('Groups')
   Groups      Names
6      G3  XP_EHHEHE
10     G4   XP_ddhhd
2      G1  YP_EIEIYE
3      G2   AOIGOEGO
```

Comment: what If I want to keep YP instead of XP when there is both ?

Comment: @chippycentra pd.Categorical(df.Names.str[:3],['YP_','XP_'])